# Versionar dados de uma tabela MySQL e PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

bom, a princípio eu tenho uma tabela chamada projetos. E eu preciso criar versões dos dados contidos nela, pois conforme OS DADOS DESSA TABELA forem passando por correções, eu preciso mostrá-las para quem for corrigindo...
Qual seria a melhor forma de gerenciar as versões dos dados contidos nela?

[image: Tabela Projetos]

Por exemplo, no título eu tenho um certo dado:

Versão 1: **Este é um título que eu quero versionar**

Agora depois de um alteração:

Versão 1: **Este é um título que eu quero versionar**
   Versão 2: **Este é um título que eu quero versionar, que está na segunda versão**

Ou seja, eu quero manter as duas versões e mostra-las ao usuário...
Seria necessário eu criar um outra tabela para isso? Não seria um gasto desnecessário de espaço em memória para tal?

Att. Agradecido.

Comment: não seria melhor você ter rotinas de backups?

Comment: Poderia colocar um novo campo na tabela com o nome de "pai", sendo integer. Nesse campo, você pode fazer referência ao ID original com os dados da versão anterior. Dessa forma, o primeiro registro (por exemplo ID 56) se o campo "pai" estiver zerado, ele é o registro original. Ao copiar os dados para um novo registro, você coloca o ID do anterior no campo "pai". Exemplo: dados copiados para o ID 98, no campo "pai" estaria o ID 56, que guarda de onde os dados vieram. Assim você pode trabalhar essa "integração" na mesma tabela, apenas criando um campo novo